# How to set Rabbit password from external secret?

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

The rabbit helm chart documentation says that if I configure

```
 auth:
    existingPasswordSecret
    existingErlangSecret
```

then rabbit will pick up these secrets from existing resources. This actually works until I enable loadDefinition in order to pre-configure virtual hosts upon chart installation:

```
extraSecrets:
  load-definition:
    load_definition.json: |
      {
        "users": [
          {
            "name": "user",
            "tags": "administrator"
          }
        ],
        "vhosts": [
            {
                "name": "development"
            },
            {
                "name": "staging"
            },
            {
                "name": "/"
            }
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "user": "user",
                "vhost": "development",
                "configure": ".*",
                "write": ".*",
                "read": ".*"
            },
            {
                "user": "user",
                "vhost": "/",
                "configure": ".*",
                "write": ".*",
                "read": ".*"
            },
            {
                "user": "user",
                "vhost": "staging",
                "configure": ".*",
                "write": ".*",
                "read": ".*"
            }
        ],
```

After enabling rabbit is not using password from external secret and password is empty.
My question - how can I still use existing secret for defining password AND preconfigure
vhosts, permissions, etc?

I've also tried to remove "users" block from definition, but then rabbit is crashing right after installation.

Comment: I assume, that rabbit uses your `values.yaml` entries to create the user, but overrides it when loading the definitions. Maybe it already helps, if you drop the user part from your `definitions.json`.

Comment: Actually it's currently not possible. Definitions are not meant to work with external secrets.  Either you have to define user in definitions or use external secret to define password for predefined `user`.